# try find a way to upload a blob to firebase and edit it with cloud functions

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I've been trying to upload a file to firestorage for a few days from firebase functions and still not successful.
This is the farthest I have come:

```js
export const tester = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
  await STORAGE.bucket("[url]").upload("dir", {
    destination: "dest",
  });

  response.send(STORAGE);
});
```

But it's still not good because I have to upload blob

And I have already tried before the examples of Google in git, but I have problems with my typescript

```js
function uploadRef() {
  // [START storage_upload_ref]
  // Create a root reference
  var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();

  // Create a reference to 'mountains.jpg'
  var mountainsRef = storageRef.child('mountains.jpg');

  // Create a reference to 'images/mountains.jpg'
  var mountainImagesRef = storageRef.child('images/mountains.jpg');

  // While the file names are the same, the references point to different files
  mountainsRef.name === mountainImagesRef.name;           // true
  mountainsRef.fullPath === mountainImagesRef.fullPath;   // false 
  // [END storage_upload_ref]
}
```

Any help ?

Comment: Can you add the list of steps you want to perform? What data are you passing to the function? Is it a `multipart/form-data` request?

Answer (score 0):

If you're uploading from Firebase functions, the file can be somewhere else within the function instance and it can either be at the functions directory (`/workspace`) or at `/tmp`. You can only save files at `/tmp`.

Make sure that [`pathString`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Bucket.html#upload) is the combination of both directory and filename. For example:

```
const path = require('path')
const admin = require("firebase-admin")

admin.initializeApp({
    storageBucket: 'my-firebase-proj.appspot.com'
});
const bucket = admin.storage().bucket();

...

const filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'filename'); //assuming the file is at /workspace
await bucket.upload(filePath, {
  destination: "dest",
});
```

*Update*: Or if you're streaming the file, consider using [`createWriteStream()`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#createWriteStream).

Comment: It is not required to be on the file system, you can pipe the request body stream straight through to Storage.